# Django dynamic localization of "translation strings"

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

a bit of background, I have a working project written in Django which is something like internet shop with a blog.
For now, my customer needs an ability to add translations and new languages on the fly. The model related part can be easily done using one of many libraries (like `django-modeltranslation`, `django-parler` ...).

The problem is with translatable strings and formatting. Updating translatable strings can be somehow covered by `django-rosseta` (works with `.po`, compiles them and reloads the server, but is it ok?). And how to handle adding new language without touching source code (`settings.LANGUAGES` section)?

Ideally, all localization-related data should be stored in the database with some kind of caching.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After a week of research, developed [a working demo](https://bitbucket.org/Dock1100/django_translations/overview), maybe it will be useful for someone.
Basic idea: store all translations in a database and rebuild localized `.mo` files if necessary.